# PHPExcel XLSM file with macros

Tags: php, laravel, macros, phpexcel, xlsm

Is it possible to read and write xlsm with macros file with phpexcel?

I tested this code just to replicate the original file:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("file1.xlsm"); 
echo ('Saving...');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('test.xlsm');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

But the new file is different from the original because he has no images.

Thank you.

Comment: How are those images embedded in the Excel file? If they're normal Excel file images, then there should be no issue... if they're generated by the macros then it's unlikely that they'll be preserved because xlsm is not explicitly supported

Comment: I don't know if is relevant but I extracted the xlsm file and the images are in a folder.

Comment: Well I guess I can look at the code and see why it won't load images from an xlsm file; except that it does in all my tests, and has done for years.... I don't really know what I can do to help

Comment: Well Mark, my project need to read the original xlsm file and write to another but first i need to test first if i can replicate the original file. I don't know if there any other way to do that.

Comment: If you're able to email the file to me, or post it on the phpexcel issues list [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/10749) I can take a look

Comment: What's your email Mark? i'll send you a copy of my file.

Comment: I sent you an email.

Comment: Have you received my emails Mark?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. I need to export from XLSM files, do you know any library or any way that can achieve this?

Comment: until now, I couldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

PHPExcel doesnot support XLSM fully. Try converting XLSM to XLSX file